# MudDataGrid SelectColumn<T> with Disabled-Func for rows that should be non-selectable

Tags: c#, mudblazor

The SelectColumn component does not provide a parameter to disable rows from selection.
If I want to to build my own component using the MudDataGrid selection, I run into problems using the `CellContext` `CellActions` when implementing my own SelectColumn component.

By copying the original code:

```
@namespace MudBlazor
@typeparam T

<TemplateColumn T="T" Tag="@("select-column")" Sortable="false" Resizable="false" ShowColumnOptions="false" HeaderStyle="width:0%"
    Filterable="false" IsEditable="false">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        @if (ShowInHeader)
        {
            <MudCheckBox T="bool" Size="@Size" Checked="@context.IsAllSelected" CheckedChanged="@context.Actions.SetSelectAllAsync" />
        }
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <CellTemplate>
        <MudCheckBox T="bool" Size="@Size" Checked="@context.IsSelected" CheckedChanged="@context.Actions.SetSelectedItemAsync" />
    </CellTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        @if (ShowInFooter)
        {
            <MudCheckBox T="bool" Size="@Size" Checked="@context.IsAllSelected" CheckedChanged="@context.Actions.SetSelectAllAsync" />
        }
    </FooterTemplate>
</TemplateColumn>
@code{
        [Parameter] public bool ShowInHeader { get; set; } = true;
        [Parameter] public bool ShowInFooter { get; set; } = true;
        [Parameter] public Size Size { get; set; } = Size.Medium;
}
```

`@context.Actions.SetSelectedItemAsync` for instance shows the following Exception (in Rider IDE)

```
Cannot resolve method 'Create(MudBlazor.MySelectColumn<T>, System.Func<bool,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)', candidates are:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>> Create<bool?>(object, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback) (in class EventCallbackFactory)   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>> Create<bool?>(object, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>>) (in class EventCallbackFactory)   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>> Create<bool?>(object, System.Action) (in class EventCallbackFactory)   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>> Create<bool?>(object, System.Action<System.Nullable<bool>>) (in class EventCallbackFactory)   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>> Create<bool?>(object, System.Func<System.Nullable<bool>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>) (in class EventCallbackFactory)   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Nullable<bool>> Create<bool?>(object, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>) (in class EventCallbackFactory)
```

How can I extend the functionality of such a component by using the `MudDataGrid`s way of saving the selection and not storing the selection in separate structures?

Comment: MudDataGrid does not support bool values atm https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/7093